# Visual Studio - Do not show current line when breaking

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Can I disable the feature of Visual Studio (2013) which shows the most recently executed code line when pausing a program?

For 95% of the cases, I break a program only to modify code, and do not want to see the current line, which mostly opens a new tab in a completely uninteresting location (like `Application.Run(new FormMain())`).

Comment: I'd love to disable this as well!